# Chrome Icon in Chrome Tags is stretched

Tags: bug, status-completed, stack-overflow, design, sponsored-tags

The Chrome icon/logo is stretched horizontally slightly in Chrome tags, making it oblong instead of circular. Here:

[image]

I've seen this in Chrome 19 and Safari on OSX.

Comment: [tag:google-chrome-extension] is affected. [tag:google-chrome] is not.

Comment: Looks like due to the length of the tag - [tag:google-chrome-devtools] is affected as well..

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The image that was being used had incorrect dimensions - this has been fixed.